# Задать универсальный роут

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework-3

Пробую делать spa приложение на ZF3. Нужен универсальный роут

Вот в Ларавел есть такая возможность

```
Route::any('{any?}', function () {
        return view('index');
    })->where('any','.*');
```

А как это можно сделать в Zend Framework 3?

Answer (score 1):

Возможно Вам подойдет `\Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Regex::class => '/(?<url>.+)'`

Answer (score 0):

Благодарю @abu, повозился и сам как-то понял. Дам все же немного развернутый ответ. Кому-нибудь пригодится.

У меня модуль базовый "App". Создал новый модуль "Api"
И вот что у меня в конфигурациях модулей

```
//module App, file: config.module.php
'routes' => [
            'home' => [
                'type' => Regex::class,
                'options' => [
                    'regex'    => '([^\?]+)(\?.*)?',
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ],
                    'spec' => ''
                ],
            ],
        ],


//module Api file:config.module.php
'routes' => [
            'api_index' => [
                'type'    => Regex::class,
                'options' => [
                    'regex'    => '/api/(?<index>[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)',
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller'    => Controller\IndexController::class,
                        'action'        => 'index',
                    ],
                    'spec' => '/api/%index%'
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

Все работает. При обращении ко всем роутам с сегментом api будет обращение к модулю Api, а во всех остальных случаях будет отвечать базовый модуль.